# $f$ - Lebesgue measurable if the undergraph is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following problem:

Let $f$ be a non-negative function defined on a Lebesgue measurable subset $ E \subset [0,1]$. Show that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable if the region $$A=\{\ (x,y): x \in E, \  f(x) \geq y\}$$is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt on a solution**:

$f: E \to [0, +\infty)$ is Lebesgue measurable $\iff$ for any $y \geq 0$ we have $f^{-1} ( [y, +\infty) ) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \cap E.$

Now notice that $ f^{-1} ( [y, +\infty) ) = \{ x \in E \ | \ f(x) \geq y \} = A^y$ - the $y$-section of the set $A$.

We can apply Cavaliery's principle for complete measures (consequence of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem for complete measures):

Since $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \overline{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})}$, we conclude that $A^y \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ for almost any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $y \in [0, + \infty)$ for that matter).

This is close, but how to get rid of the "almost any $y$" part?

**Update**:

I finally found a slightly different approach which allows to take care of this nuisance (essentially that is what William hinted at in the comments):

Define the set $F=A \cap ( E \times [0, +\infty) )=\{ (x,y) \ | \ x \in E, f(x) \geq y \geq 0 \} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Take the indicator $\chi_F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is therefore measurable.

Applying Fubini-Tonelli's theorem for complete measures, we get that almost everywhere defined function $g(x) = \int \chi_{F}^{x} (y) d \lambda(y) = \lambda (\{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ f(x) \geq y \geq 0 \}  ) = f(x)$ is measurable.

Going back to the proof of Fubini-Tonelli's thm for complete measures, we see that $g(x)$ can be extended to a measurable function (that is what people mean when they use the term "almost everywhere defined"). Anyway, we get that $f(x)$ is almost everywhere equal to a measurable function, and since we are on a complete measure space, the result follows.

Comment: Don't you only need the statement to be true for "almost any" $y$ in order to get the desired conclusion? I am probably overlooking something important.

Comment: @William, I always thought the condition for measurable $f$ is that $f^{-1} ([y, +\infty))$ is measurable for any $y$. Otherwise it means that I can find a certain $y$, such that $[y, + \infty)$ is a Borel set, but it's preimage is not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Is it possible to define a new function $\tilde{f}$ that is set to $0$ on the negligible set of bad behavior, and therefore is measurable? And then since $f = \tilde{f}$ everywhere except on a negligible set, and $\tilde{f}$ is measurable, you can conclude that $f$ is measurable? I haven't done a problem like this in a while so I think I might be over-simplifying. Anyway usually one just ignores the bad behavior in these situations if it occurs on a set of measure zero -- I should check this though.

Comment: @William, yes, I tried to think along these lines, but I cannot produce a rigorous argument.

Comment: Neither can I, sorry -- I'm not sure how to prove that $\{  (-\infty,y] : y\in \mathbb{R} \setminus A: \mu(A)=0\}$ generates the same $\sigma$-algebra as $\{ (-\infty, y] : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ -- honestly the more I think about it the more I suspect that it might not. Anyway, I want to say that because $f$ is non-negative, we should be able to find a workaround. Or maybe just use open infinite intervals $(-\infty, y)$? Actually I don't think that really makes a difference, although maybe if you combine both you can say something about the inverse images of points which would help you somehow.

Comment: @William, Take a look at the update of my question, I think I found a convincing solution.

Comment: Your convincing solution is even more convincing than you think.  $g(x)$ is *everywhere* defined because the indicator $\chi_F^x$ is measurable for *every* $x$ (for any given $x$ it is simply the indicator of an interval), so the integral of it is well defined and equals $f(x)$.  No big theorems or a.e. disclaimers needed here. You just need Fubini to assert that the function defined by this formula is in fact measurable.

Comment: @NateEldredge, ah, I see. Thank you!